# Tomcat not starting after applying last redhat kernel patch

Tags: security, tomcat, linux-kernel, patch

After applying RHSA-2013:0911:R6-32 (Important: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 kernel update), tomcat refuses to start with a

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

error in the catalina.out log.

In our particular environment, we are using RHEL 32 bits with 2 GB RAM machines. The new kernel is: 2.6.32-358.11.1.el6.i686

The config is pretty default, only a -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M is configured. (I know, it's high). If I decrease that value less than 800M, tomcat starts.

If I boot with the previous kernel (2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.i686) , tomcat starts.

It looks the new kernel changed some memory allocation behaviour...Are there more people with mem issues?

Comment: Confirmed by Redhat...there were some changes in the memory allocation and now java cannot allocate 1024M as maxpermsize on RHEL 32bits. I found out it wasnt a needed parameter, so the issue was "solved".

Comment: After applying the last kernel, the issue has gone. It looks like there was a problem with that particular kernel version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Centos 32bit using this kernel, as well as the most recent one kernel-firmware-2.6.32-358.14.1.el6. http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=6529 suggests using sysctl vm.unmap_area_factor=1 to influence how memory is allocated. However, it didn't do the trick for me. I'll migrate to a 64 bit installation now.